# How do I add ipynb notebooks which are outside docs directory where sphinx processes documentation?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-sphinx, nbsphinx

I have the following folder structure for my project. There are .ipynb notebooks in `examples` which I want to be rendered by sphinx using the nbsphinx extension.

[image: folder structure]

I did not have issues when `examples` folder lied inside `doc`. I restructured the folders and brought `examples` outside `doc`, and I am not able to do a relative import. I have searched on github and stackoverflow but did not come across any solutions.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.